# hide WebStorm toolbar showing browser icons

Tags: ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How do I hide the toolbar that shows browser icons floating above my code?

I'm using WebStorm 64 bit, version 10.0.4, on Windows 8.1 x64.

[image]

Comment: What an annoying feature.  I do not want a browser popping up when simply trying to edit the markup. It's ridiculous to have that as the default, if not a ridiculous feature entirely.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences`
2. `Tools | Web Browsers`
3. Uncheck `Show browser popup in the editor` option (bottom part of the screen)

[image]

**Since 2020.3 version** you have a bit better control over file types:

[image]

---

Another possible solution: just disable all browsers in that list.

Comment: Thank you! Of course this is under Tools.  not under View.  or Appearance.  or anywhere else you might expect it to be... :)

Comment: @Adam **Hint:** settings screen has search functionality -- try using it. Once you start using it you will soon realise that exact location does not really matter if you know the setting name. **P.S.** `Help | Find Action..` as well as `Search Everywhere` functionality can also search trough settings and allow to turn on/off most of them directly from results list.

Comment: There's no settings tab for me..there's a file -> settings tab. But not a settings tab. Phpstorms UI is so so bad..

Comment: @user2879055 The UI is fine. Search field (top left side) also works fine and allows to short list possible settings (try typing `browser` there). See the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/24F5F.png -- I've updated answer to match latest IDE version (2018.2)

Comment: For anyone with 2020.3+, now you can only check/uncheck `For HTML files` and `For XML files` and maybe more (I am using PHPStorm), so you will not see `Show browser popup in the editor` anymore.