# PhpStorm - remove browser icons

Tags: phpstorm

I try to edit the code behind the browser icons, but I can't because they are in the way.

[image]

Is there a way to remove them?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Go to **File -> Settings -> Tools -> Web Browsers**,

Un-check "Show browser popup in the editor" in the bottom.

Comment: Thanks, now I can start developing again..

Comment: likewise, horrible little feature.

Comment: Note that this checkbox is now split into "For HTML files" and "For XML files" and if you're wondering, yes - PHP files count as HTML files (for some reason).

Comment: This answer is for an old version. For latest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31761953/1145134