# JetBrains RustRover - Disable Browser Icons Popup

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rustrover

I have this popup of browser icons in all rust files in a project when using RustRover. Clicking the icons seem to have no effect, not sure what causes it to popup. Is there any way to get rid of it?

[image]

I've tried suggestions from [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206999745-Is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-floating-browser-icons-) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760756/hide-webstorm-toolbar-showing-browser-icons), but it hasn't had any effect.

My current `Settings | Tools | Web Browsers` settings:

[image]

Comment: 1) So what do you have right now at `Settings/Preferences | Tools | Web browsers` (or whatever the right place that would be in RustRover). Show a screenshot -- interested to see what options are available there (should be the same as in other JetBrains IDEs -- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rust/editing-html-files.html). 2) Does the issue persists after restarting the IDE? 3) Does it appear for any file or a specific file/file type only.

Comment: 4) Will disabling any custom (not bundled by default) plugins and restarting the IDE make any difference? 5) I do not see any relevant tickets for this yet with my quick search: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RUST?q=browser

Comment: @LazyOne I have included a screenshot of my settings. Happens for any file type I've opened so far. I will note that it only happens after `cargo check` has completed after reopening the IDE. This is on a fresh install with non-bundled plugins installed.

I will note, this is happening only on WSL projects, and I can confirm it doesn't happen on a standard Windows project.

Comment: The screenshot looks fine.  So it's a Remote Development/Host... Looks like it's https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GTW-6023 / https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GTW-5627 (or related to them). They are marked as fixed in the next major **2023.3** version (EAP 6 build). What RustRover version do you have? I do not think those will be available in the current build (Released on October 24, 2023), so wait for the next build and check there -- https://www.jetbrains.com/rust/nextversion/

Comment: I'm on 2023.3; 233.8263.22; Oct 11.  Thanks for the info @LazyOne I'll wait for update

Comment: So ... does it work OK now (in the latest EAP build)?

Comment: @LazyOne This does appear to be working now, I don't see the browser icons after updating to the latest EAP build. Thank you!